# In mysql8.0 mysql_query(connection, "SELECT * from newtab") is not returning the correct value of column size if data type is char/varchar

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-8.0

I am trying to fetch the column length(data type is char) using mysql_query() in mysql8.0. But every time I get the value (actualsize of column)*4. But in case of int it is correct.
If I connect the same program with mysql5.7 it shows the correct column length.

my table description is here.

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| empName | char(10)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| empID   | int         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| empAdd  | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mysql.h>
int main(char** args) {
    MYSQL_RES* result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL* connection, mysql;
    int state; /* connect to the mySQL database at athens.imaginary.com */
    mysql_init(&mysql);
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "Welcome@1", "mysql", 0, NULL,0); /* check for a connection error */
    if (connection == NULL) {
        /* print the error message */
        printf(mysql_error(&mysql));
        return 1;
    }
    state = mysql_query(connection, "SELECT * from newtab");
    if (state != 0) {
        printf(mysql_error(connection));
        return 1;
    }
    printf("lenghth::%d\n", connection->fields->length);
    mysql_close(connection);
    printf("Done.\n");
    getchar();
}
```

every time **connection->fields->length** shows the empName col size 40.

I am expecting the actual size should be 10 only.